# Can someone follow the opposite minhag on the bracha for matza during the year?

Tags: halacha, minhag, blessing, meal-seudah, matzah

The Ashkenazic custom is to wash and say hamotzi on matza all year round. The Sephardi custom is to make mezonot when it's not Pesach.

Is someone allowed to follow the opposite minhag?

I have heard precedent for sometimes washing and sometimes saying mezonot. For example, pizza. I wash if i'm *kove'ah seudah*, but not if i'm having it as a snack. The same with certain "breadsticks" and biscuits.

So now, the question can be interpreted as: Can an Ashkenazi decide that he is just having matza as a snack, and not wash; and can a Sfardi decide to be *kove'ah seudah* on matza?

Comment: The koveah seudah consideration doesn't apply for all mezonos. Only pas habah b'kisnin

Comment: To the closevoter, this is not asking for psak. It seems a bit too general for that.

Comment: Also CYLOR about pizza. Most rabbis I have met say to wash for pizza even as a snack

Comment: That Sephardi custom is only about hard matza which they are treating as a cracker. Soft matza wouldn't have that property.

Answer (score 1):

Your question spans two areas:

- What is the consideration of the bracha of matzah during the non-Pesach time of the year?
- Can I change my minhag just because I want to (from my inference of your question)?

To answer the 1st question, you may want to read [this Chaf-K article](http://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108090405W-8%20Hamotzei%20Vs%20Mezonos.pdf) that discuses how and if matzah and matzah crackers fall into the category of *pat haba b'kisnin* as there are differing opinions. Understanding the foundations of the discussion may help you understand why the brachot are what they are, prior to your deciding if there is a valid reason to "change minhag".

As to whether you can change your minhag on this, CYLOR.